# Partition if applicable

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, partition

I have a column in a dataframe with approx 1,4M rows of chat conversations of which the general format in each cell is (1):

'*name agent* *:* *conversation*'

However, not all cells in the column hold this format. Some cells are simply (2):

'*conversation*'

I use the following code to get only the *conversation* for the cells that are structured like (1):

```
only_transcripts['msgText'] = only_transcripts['msgText'].str.partition(':', expand = True)[2]
```

However, obviously this code returns nothing if a cell does not contain a colon (**:**).

Is there a quick way, in which I can avoid a for loop to loop through each instance, to only apply the above code in cells that contain a colon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) by original column for replace `NaN`s, here is also another solution with `split` and seelct second lists by indexing

```
only_transcripts['msgText'] =(only_transcripts['msgText'].str.split(':')
                                                         .str[1]
                                                         .fillna(only_transcripts['msgText']))
```